# The best way to make a viewcontroller for different screens

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2, ios9

I would like to know which is the best way to make a view controller for iOS 9 swift 2 xcode 7, for different iPhone screens?

I have tried to make it with constrains but from iphone 4s to iphone 6s screens we can see wide gaps between the icons and text fields etc.

What i'm thinking is to make different view controllers for each screen (5.5inches, 4.7inches, 3.5inches) and to make my app check with which screen the user is opening the app and load the unigue view controller for this screen.

Or maybe there is a better way but im new to swift 2.0 so i'm asking for your help!

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Using constraints should solve your problems, if you see some gaps maybe because you didn't setup constraints in the right way. Don't create views for different screen size, it's a lot of work and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a views for multiple screens using autolyout and size classes. You have proportional constraints that fit on all screens.

Proportional constraints means you can set for example view1 is 50% of screen.
These constraints fit on all screens.

Avoid excessive use of size classes (applying constraint in different size class). Try to go with proportional constraints in hAny wAny layout.

Only go for different size class if design on ipad is different then iphone. Or if you need different font sizes on different devices.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/chapters/EditingConstraintAttributesintheAttributesInspector.html

Answer (score 1):

I think this depends upon what your requirement is and what you prefer.
I usually prefer the good old `Springs and Struts`.
They can be used by disabling auto layout and screen sizes.
Using `Springs and Struts` i only create a single `Storyboard` to manage all `iPhone` and `iPad` screen sizes without any coding effort.
No matter how complex the UI maybe, for me `Springs and Struts` are the best solution.

Comment: Can you provide some links example? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Size classes give you a more fine grain control for different sizes and orientations. Please refer [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH6-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

As I understood your question that you want to load storyboard as size of screen of device.

I will suggest you to refer this link to load a different storyboard depending on screen size. Sorry for Objective c but hope it helps you.
[Load different storyboards](http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-load-a-different-storyboard-depending-on-screen-size-in-ios/)